# %40 is not getting decoded to @ in Jmeter

Tags: csv, encoding, jmeter

I'm trying Jmeter tool for load testing where i'm feeding the data through a csv file which has all the emails and passwords for login request. But while passing the parameter, Jmeter is encoding '@' sign with '%40' and if i put %40 in place of @ in my csv, its not getting decoded to @ in Jmeter. For other special characters, the encoding and decoding is happening properly. Please help.

Comment: Any solution to this issue. I am facing the same

Answer (score 0):

It should be totally expected.

If you're logging in via GET request `%40` is correct way of encoding `@` symbol.

If you're sending a POST request, JMeter should automatically send `@` symbol (at least my JMeter 2.10 does)

You might wish to try one of following:

1. Add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener, switch to `HTTP` tab and see what's actually being sent.
2. Make sure that `Encode?` box is unchecked for email parameter
3. Explicitly tell JMeter to decode email via [__urldecode()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) function
4. Use a [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to properly encode/decode your email

   ```
   import java.net.URLDecoder;
   import java.net.URLEncoder;

   String email = "someone@example.com";
   String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");
   String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(encoded, "UTF-8");
   ```

Comment: Dmitri, Its happening the other way round. In GET request, I'm able to see @ in the parameters and in POST request, it is getting encoded. Check boxes are unchecked too. Ideally email should not be getting encoded but in my case it is.

Comment: You can try one of following:
1. HTTP Authorization Manager (under Config Elements)
2. Pass your email and password in request like http://email:password@your.domain. 

If you need to provide email as parameter - it must be encoded.

Answer (score 0):

This is coming when we do via Parameters,
If we do using "Body Data" that would work fine.

I used this way.
{"password":"${password}","emailId":"${emailId}"}

Answer (score 0):

For the HTTP Request, Change the Client implementation to Java

1. Select the Advanced tab from the HTTP Request
2. In Client Implementation > Choose Java in Implementation

[image]