# Jmeter. When getting user emails from csv, @ replaced by %40

Tags: jmeter

I have scenario where I'm passing POST request to log in but when I look into request I can see @ is being replaced with %40 and it cause login to fail. Can I avoid this replacement? Thanks

Comment: Possible dup [%40 is not getting decoded to @ in Jmeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367372/40-is-not-getting-decoded-to-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have "Encode?" box ticked for relevant param?

[image: Param Encode]

[image: Param Decode Results]

If you're using variable retrieved from CSV differently (i.e. in URL, Header or wherever) you can use the following JMeter Functions to decode it:

- [__unescapeHtml](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__unescapeHtml) - to decode HTML-encoded entities
- [__urldecode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urldecode) - to decode URL-encoded entities

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for comprehensive information on different JMeter's functions.