# Valid Credentials are not working if pass through csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

In response ,credentials along with special character are coming.
For example, i am trying to run a test with multiple logged in user having credentials such as 989898-98989 but in response %22%98989-98989%22 is coming that results in failed test as unable to login with this credential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your CSV has valid data. There should be comma-separated values in it.

It seems that your are using spaces after and before commas. Please remove if there are spaces and then try again.

If you still face the issue then share more details about CSV file and the CSV data set config.

Comment: Thanks for the information,but my problem is not solved,this time it is accepting the credentials but showing message in response"Please enter correct username and password" whereas the credentials i am passing is valid,its not wrong.So still unable to login.

Comment: So the special characters problem is resolved now ? Have you checked the sent username & password values in TreeView Listener (under request tab) ?

Comment: If you are sending correct request with correct credentials and still getting the message then may be there are additional security checks in your login request? May be any other additional parameter is sent in your login request that you missed? You can identify that by either analyzing all of login request parameters or simply discuss with application developer.

Comment: Special character problem is solved in case if am sending 9898-1234 as username and 9898-1234  as password but when i am sending abc@gmail.com as username ,in response i am getting abc%40gmail.com in view result tree.Also, i am still unable to login,do you have any other solution,other than you provide up there(security checks and all).Any other problem than that?because no parameter other than this 2 are required to login.

Comment: I really can't help much unless you can provide me jmx file (with recording). For troubleshooting, you can initially send the hardcoded values (instead of values from CSV). That way you will be able to further narrow down the problem. It will help you know if the issue is with CSV or your request or security.

Comment: Okay,but what is the problem in sending the username as "abc@gmail.com" and in response "abc%40gmail.com".It is replacing  the @ with %40.I have hard coded the value but username in response is coming wrong.Is special character are not allowed(@)

Comment: conversion of @ to %40 is normal and expected. Jmeter automatically handles it send valid value. check following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20367372/40-is-not-getting-decoded-to-in-jmeter

Comment: If you are getting issues even after using hardcoded values then problem is not with csv data but your requests. As I said before you will need to discuss with application developer if there are any additional security checks in your login request. In most of applications there is always such checks. Passwords are sent in encrypted form. So you will need to discuss it.